# Does Versioning only work for MS Word Documents?

Tags: versioning

Does the versioning option in SharePoint 2013 only work for Microsoft Word Documents? What about Excel or PowerPoint?

Can I do Versioning with Tasks as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Both lists and libraries can use Versioning, the file type does not matter in the case of documents.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Versioning works with all document types and different list options.

> Versioning is available for list items in all default list types—including calendars, issue tracking lists, and custom lists. It is also available for all file types that can be stored in libraries, including Web Part pages.

[See Microsoft Article Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-does-versioning-work-in-a-list-or-library-0f6cd105-974f-44a4-aadb-43ac5bdfd247?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)